# Unknown symbol and item that has baffled me

Tags: python

from this code,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return x*x*np.sqrt(x+1)

# prepare coordinate vectors
x = np.linspace(-1, 1.5, 500)
y = f(x)

# create figure and axes
fig, ax  = plt.subplots(1,1)

# format spines 
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data', 0))
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', 0))

# plot and format
ax.plot(x,y, 'r-')
ax.plot([-1, -4/5, 0], [f(-1), f(-4/5), f(0)], linestyle="", marker='o', mfc='b', mec='r')
ax.set_xlabel(r'$x$'); ax.set_title(r'$y =  x^2\sqrt{x+1}$')
ax.set_xlim([-1.5,1.5])
ax.annotate('local max', xy=(-4/5-0.05, f(-4/5)+0.1),  xycoords='data', xytext=(-1.2, 1.5), 
            ha='right', va='top', arrowprops={'fc':'blue',}            
            )


# save the figure
fig.savefig('sketch.png')
plt.show()
```

What is the '$' sign mean in python?

thank you.I was trying to search on internet but cannot really understand it,thank you.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything in Python. It *is* used as a delimiter for LaTeX in Markdown though, and that's exactly what it's being used for here.

Comment: The `$` sign does not mean anything special in Python.  It looks like it has special meaning for figure labels.

Answer (score 1):

The $ doesn't mean anything in Python - it's just that character in a string. Matplotlib uses it for rendering LaTeX: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/usetex.html

Comment: So i can also put the code above without key in the '$' sign? does that didnt gave me error or something?

Comment: @YiZheHiew, did you try it? Of course you can, but the LaTeX won't be rendered in that case. Try it and you'll see the difference in your title, for example.